# Repeated events in Eventbrite API

Tags: api, events, search, eventbrite

I noticed that when I search future events via event_search method, sorted by date, that first events in result-set have start date from past. Problem with these events is that they are repeatable events (e.g. weekly), but API does not return events' recurrence type (daily, weekly, monthly, other). Method should at least return next event start date and recurrance type.

Answer (score 8):

**Hidden feature:**

Add "display=repeat_schedule" to your API requests to reveal a series of start_date, end_date pairs for each repeating instance.

Comment: This works and is a much better solution than trying to parse the string that normally gets returned under the 'repeat_schedule' key. How did you find out about this undocumented parameter?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, Eventbrite's "repeating events" feature (available on their website) is not totally compatible with their API services:

Most storage models have an associated identifier or 'handle' to reference each asset or resource.  In REST-speak these identifiers are known as 'resource ids'.
Eventbrite's repeating events share a single event id, and they include a string that describes the schedule when they repeat.

The head of the chain of repeating events is returned, with a "repeats" attribute that is set to "yes".  And, the "repeat_schedule" attribute should now be present on all repeating events.

The string that is revealed will have a different format depending how the event is configured to repeat:

Daily repeating events:

- "daily-4-07/26/2012" - every fourth day, from the date/time of the
  start_date until 2012-07-26.
- "daily-mf-07/26/2012" - every Monday
  through Friday, from the start_date day/time until "2012-07-26"

Weekly repeating events:

- "weekly-3-Y,N,N,N,N,N,N-09/16/2012" - every 3rd week, on each day marked with a "Y" until "2012-09-16"

Monthly repeating events:

- "monthly-2-10-06/30/2012" - every second month, on the 10th day of the month until "2012-06-30"
- "monthly-2-second/sat-06/30/2012" - every second month, on the second Saturday of that month, until "2012-06-30".
  Custom repeat schedule (not fully supported):
- "custom-3199915" - This format is really rare. Unfortunately, these events can not be easily summarized using a single string.

Answer (score 2):

This bug needs to be fixed by EventBrite

However Would this work has a temp workaround?  I would work in some examples I have seen.

I make request for events on March 17, 2012

I get back a past date

```
<repeats>yes</repeats>
<start_date>2011-12-04 09:30:00</start_date>
<end_date>2011-12-04 10:30:00</end_date>
```

Can I assume this is a repeating event that occcurs on March 17, 2012
at the same times?

Answer (score 0):

There's a new endpoint that can be used to fetch all the events that are part of a series, the only values required are: `OAuth Token` and the `event_series_id` which is the parent event ID or the ID of the event where the series was created.

This is the endpoint:

```
GET - https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/series/{event_series_id}/events/
```

Replace `{event_series_id}` with your event series ID.

More details at: https://www.eventbrite.com/platform/api#/reference/event/list/list-events-by-series